# How to make Parameters of VB.NET function as Generic type?

Tags: vb.net, function, generics, generic-programming

I have a VB.NET function as below, the parameter 'x' that is passed to the function is of Type 'Single'. However, I want to write the function so that it can accept any numeric type such as 'Single', 'Double' and 'Integer'. I know one way of doing that is to write 3 functions with the same names, but it would be so tedious. Can anyone suggest any idea? Thank you.

```
Public Function Square(x As Single) As Single
  Return x * x
End Function
```

Comment: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html

Comment: Complementary link http://converter.telerik.com/ - It doesn't seem to play too well with lambdas (Or VB just sucks that much? I don't know)

Comment: Although its pretty easy to do generic functions. You can't use operators in the method body.

Comment: That method is not really a good candidate for being generic because there's no constraint that you can apply to a generic type parameter that will include all the types you want and exclude all others.  There's no common base type or interface that just numeric types inherit or implement.  You should stick with overloading.  Don't use features like generics just because you can.

Answer (score 11):

try following method

```
Public Function Square(Of T)(ByVal x As Object) As T
    Dim b As Object = Val(x) * Val(x)
    Return CType(b, T)
End Function
```

You can use above function like this

```
Dim p As Integer = Square(Of Integer)(10)
Dim d As Double = Square(Of Double)(1.5)
```

Comment: I am just curious about How expensive it would be if that function is called quite a lot. Apparently CType would take some computational resources?

Answer (score 2):

You can constrain the generic type by [`IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Structure`. The following data types implements the IConvertible interface:

- System.Boolean
- System.Byte
- System.Char
- System.DateTime
- System.DBNull
- System.Decimal
- System.Double
- System.Enum
- System.Int16
- System.Int32
- System.Int64
- System.SByte
- System.Single
- System.String
- System.UInt16
- System.UInt32
- System.UInt64

Here's a rewrite of the code found in the link provided by SLaks:

```vb
Public Function Square(Of T As {IConvertible, Structure})(x As T) As T
    'TODO: If (GetType(T) Is GetType(Date)) Then Throw New InvalidOperationException()
    Dim left As ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(T), "x")
    Dim right As ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(T), "x")
    Dim body As BinaryExpression = Expression.Multiply(left, right)
    Dim method As Func(Of T, T, T) = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, T, T))(body, left, right).Compile()
    Return method(x, x)
End Function
```

**Reference**: https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html

Answer (score 2):

The code allows any value to posted via Arg but only numeric values will be processed.  The returned value must be double because Val returns double only.

The Of T allows for generic object types to be presented.

```
   Private Function sqr(Of T)(Arg As T) As Double
    If IsNumeric(Arg) Then
        Return Val(Arg) * Val(Arg)
    Else
        Return 0
    End If

  End Function
```

Comment: will accept most values but will only return a value for a numeric.

Comment: Please explain your answer